# DIV inside <tr> block

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add a `<div></div>` block inside a `<tr>` block after the end of `<td>` blocks. But it shifts to above table. For example, I want to do this.

```html
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
          <th>Header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Info 1</td>
          <td>Info 2</td>
          <td>Info 3</td>
          <td>Info 4</td>
          <div class="progressInfo">
             <div class="progressBar">A horizontal plane progress bar here stating the completion of the work done.</div>
             <div class="textStatus">209133 left    444444 teams</div>
          </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But the `<div></div>` shifts to top of the table. Any way I can accomplish this? Also, I am using Bootstrap.

CSS

```
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>thead>tr>th {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee
}
```

Comment: <div> can be added inside <td> but not <tr>

Comment: <td> stands for "table data" you can only put data here, not in <tr> (table row)

Comment: then can that <td> break the line and come to the next line?

Comment: see my answer @AurazoScript

Comment: You mean something like a footer to the table?

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis yes I guess so.. That seems to be a more relevant context in terms of my question. BUT not a footer to the table but a footer to every <tr> block

Comment: @AurazoScript by footer of every tr you mean: one <tr> then your <div> then one <tr> then your <div> etc? Why not just add additionnal <tr> between all existing <tr> ?

Comment: can you show how?

Comment: @AurazoScript see my answer, if this is not what u mean, can you be more specific?

Comment: please look at updated answer  @AurazoScript

Answer (score 2):

you need to make a new row `<tr>` and add `colspan="4"` to td

```css
.table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table>tbody>tr
 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 1</td>
      <td>Info 2</td>
      <td>Info 3</td>
      <td>Info 4</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
      <div class="progressInfo">
         <div class="progressBar">A horizontal plane progress bar here stating the completion of the work done.</div>
         <div class="textStatus">209133 left    444444 teams</div>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Info 1</td>
      <td>Info 2</td>
      <td>Info 3</td>
      <td>Info 4</td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
      <div class="progressInfo">
         <div class="progressBar">A horizontal plane progress bar here stating the completion of the work done.</div>
         <div class="textStatus">209133 left    444444 teams</div>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in this case here there is no css.. but in my case after every tr block there is a border bottom.. so this will make is look like another block. Which is not the case. It should be in the same block as this div contains info for that particular row only.

Comment: otherwise even I could have done it already.. placing in a new tr was the 1st thing I tried already.

Comment: @AurazoScript can you share the css code? It will be easier to help.

Comment: please wait.. give me  a minute

Comment: @Firefly css shared.. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Info 1</td>
    <td>Info 2</td>
    <td>Info 3</td>
    <td>Info 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div class="progressInfo">
        <div class="progressBar">A horizontal plane progress bar here stating the completion of the work done.</div>
        <div class="textStatus">209133 left 444444 teams</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no.. but in the next line after the fourth td block.. It should break the line.. sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: also, I already tried this one. It was a simple first thing to try. I want that div to come down to the next line below the td blocks. possible?

Comment: check my edit now, you can use 'colspan' to define the with of cell :)

Comment: in this case here there is no css.. but in my case after every tr block there is a border bottom.. so this will make is look like another block. Which is not the case. It should be in the same block as this div contains info for that particular row only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 1</td>
      <td>Info 2</td>
      <td>Info 3</td>
      <td>Info 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <div class="progressInfo">
           <div class="progressBar">A horizontal plane progress bar here stating the completion of the work done.</div>
           <div class="textStatus">209133 left    444444 teams</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this doesn't bring it down to the next line. also, it extends the existing td's width. that's not what I am looking for mate.

Comment: are you want to remove border from last TR, correct?

Comment: no man.. I just want this div block within every tr. The border will be there after every tr.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **div** tag inside **tr** tag doesn't make any sense. You might have to add the div part in **td** tag

Answer (score 0):

A footer to every `<tr>` like this?

```css
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>thead>tr>th {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <div class="progressInfo">
         <div class="progressBar">A horizontal plane progress bar here stating the completion of the work done.</div>
         <div class="textStatus">209133 left    444444 teams</div>
      </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 1</td>
      <td>Info 2</td>
      <td>Info 3</td>
      <td>Info 4</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <div class="progressInfo">
         <div class="progressBar">A horizontal plane progress bar here stating the completion of the work done.</div>
         <div class="textStatus">209133 left    444444 teams</div>
      </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
      
</table>
```